# Incompatible Pointer with Custom MKAnnotationView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mkannotationview

In my taxi app I've created a custom MKAnnotationView to display the driver's estimated location. It's pretty simple:

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface EstimatedArrivalView : MKAnnotationView

- (void)setText:(NSString *)min :(NSString *)time;

@end
```

However, when I try to implement the following code on my ViewController:

```
EstimatedArrivalView *av = [_fullScreenMapView viewForAnnotation:driverPoint];
[av setText:@"MIN" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", etaTimeCount]];
```

I get the following warning:

```
Incompatible pointer types initializing 'EstimatedArrivalView *' with an expression of type 'MKAnnotationView * _Nullable'
```

As far as I understand, I'm initializing the EstimatedArrivalView as an MKAnnotationView. So why the warning?

Answer (score 1):

I think to solve this error you should try casting the MKAnnotationView as an EstimatedArrivalView like this:

```
EstimatedArrivalView *av = (EstimatedArrivalView *)[_fullScreenMapView viewForAnnotation:driverPoint];
```